# Фильтрация значений django из выпадающего списка

Tags: python, django

Имеется поле для выбора жанра книги:

```
<select class="filter" name="filter">
  {% for genre in Genres %}
    <option value="{{genre}}">{{genre}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

И вывод всех книг, выбранного жанра:

```
{% for book in Books %}
  {% if book.genre == 'sport' }
    <img src='/static/media/{{book.img\}}' class="img">
    <h5> {{book.name}} </h5>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе жанра в выпадающем списке, результаты фильтровались по этому жанру (вместо 'sport' было то, что выбрал пользователь).

Каким способом это можно реализовать?

Файл models.py:

```
class Genres(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: делаешь view которая принимает get запрос c параметром genre, и отображает эту страницу с соответствующими книгами, или со всеми книгами в случае пустого параметра.
В шаблоне добавляешь кнопку submit которая отправляет форму

Answer (score 0):

Убираем условие:

```
{% if book.genre == 'sport' }
{% endif %}
```

Вместо фильтра на сайте:

```
<select class="filter" name="filter">
  {% for genre in Genres %}
    <option value="{{genre}}">{{genre}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Создаём GET запрос:

```
<form method=GET>
  {{ Genre }}
</form>
```

С помощью GET запроса фильтруем значения в файле views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.GET:
        books = Book.objects.filter(genre__name__exact=request.GET['Genre']) #filter
    else:
        books = Book.objects.all()
    genres = GenreChoiceField()
    context = {
        'Books':books,
        'Genre':genres,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```